# Converting ASP.Net Web Form to User Control OnPreInit event

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, onpreinit

I'm in the process of converting an ASP.Net webform into a User control and there an event that now says

```
no suitable method found to override
```

the event code causing the compile error

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    //do some stuff
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Is there any equivalent for a user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnInit` override is available. The User Control Lifecycle on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775(VS.71).aspx) should help you in determining which event to correctly override. In any case what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

No.  You'll have to use Init.  I cannot think of anything I've ever done in PreInit that couldn't be done in Init just as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol_events.aspx